# Boolean Selection of loc and no loc

Tags: pandas

Is there a different of the following?

```
dfCombined[col][dfCombined[col].isnull()]
dfCombined[col].loc[dfCombined[col].isnull()]
```

And I checked that `iloc`, and `ix`, they does not support boolean selection?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filtering column `col` use `loc`:

```
dfCombined.loc[dfCombined[col].isnull(), 'col']
```

If need all columns `loc` can be omit:

```
dfCombined[dfCombined[col].isnull()]
```

Sample:

```
dfCombined = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,np.nan],
                   'col1':[4,5,6]})

print (dfCombined)
   col  col1
0  1.0     4
1  2.0     5
2  NaN     6

print (dfCombined.loc[dfCombined['col'].isnull(), 'col'])
2   NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64

#select second column (1)
print (dfCombined.ix[dfCombined['col'].isnull(), 1])
2    6
Name: col1, dtype: int64

print (dfCombined.iloc[dfCombined['col'].isnull(), 1])
NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

print (dfCombined[dfCombined['col'].isnull()])
   col  col1
2  NaN     6
```

To your question:

Works both approaches, but  more prefered is `ix` and `loc` for selecting column(s) - see [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#if-then).

```
print (dfCombined['col'][dfCombined['col'].isnull()])
2   NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64

print (dfCombined['col'].loc[dfCombined['col'].isnull()])
2   NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

In pandas `df.iloc` works only for boolean values

Example:

```
df.iloc[df[‘col’]==False/True]
```

where as `df.loc` works for non-boolean values

Example:

```
df.loc[df[‘col’]==values]
```